# provided chart vs chart provided

Tags: grammar, difference, noun-phrases, postpositive-adjectives

Which one is correct?

> The **provided charts** illustrate the information about employment.

or

> The **charts provided** illustrate the information about employment.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these options are grammatically correct.
However, if you have to pick between the two, the second option sounds a bit better.
i.e. The charts provided illustrate the information about employment.